# Ubuntu 18.04 on VirtualBox Version 5.2.12 r122591:

Tags: software-installation, virtualbox, guest-additions

I have installed the virtual box 5.2.12 on my Macbook (High Sierra)
Then I've installed Ubuntu thanks to `ubuntu-18.04.desktop-amd64.iso`.
So far so good even though it is really slow.

Then I've installed (`sudo apt-get install`) `gcc`, `make`, `perl` in order to install VirtualBox Extension Pack (`Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.2.12.vbox-extpack`).

Finally reboot the virtual machine and I'm stuck.

```
[OK] started daemon for power management
stopping User Manager for UID 120...
```

I found similar threads but I did not find the right way to fix it!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Why did you Perl from source? It's installed by default in Ubuntu because some core system management tools rely on it. See [How do I install Guest Additions in a VirtualBox VM?](https://askubuntu.com/q/22743/175814) and how it doesn't mention any Perl installations.

Comment: @David Forester, Thanks for the answer. The reason why I installed perl is because Guest Additions pack  told me so. It seems that gcc and make are mandatory. I have no idea why perl was mentioned. To be precise here is the command I used : sudo apt-get install build-essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's absolutely no need to install Perl or any other prerequisites *from source* to install guest additions. All of them are either installed by default in Ubuntu because other default system components rely on them (e. g. Perl) or are available in the official package repositories (see the last step below).

If so far all you did with this virtual machine was to install Ubuntu, Perl and maybe guest additions the most economic solution is to

1. shut down the machine,
2. reinstall Ubuntu from scratch and
3. refer to [How do I install Guest Additions in a VirtualBox VM?](/q/22743/175814) for the installation of guest additions.

To track down and resolve the specific issue caused by the installation of Perl would likely be a waste of everybody's time in comparison.

Comment: I followed your recommandations and I did not have the frozen issue anymore. I think installing dkms might be the key of such a success. Thank for your your help. Now I need to understand why the drag'n'drop does not work and why the VM (unity) is so slow. But these are others topics...